# How do I populate chart.js labels with array items?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

In chart.js when I try to fill labels with array items, it will display one bar with all array items as 1 label. 


**My expected result:**

Amount of bars: 2

Labels: "val 1", "val 2"

**Actual Result:**
Amount of bars: 1

Labels: "val 1 val 2"

**Code:**

```
function getData() {
    return ["val 1", "val 2"];
}

// Bar Chart Example
var ctx = document.getElementById("myBarChart");
var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
      labels: [getData()],
    datasets: [{
      label: "Aantal voldoendes",
      backgroundColor: "#4e73df",
      hoverBackgroundColor: "#2e59d9",
      borderColor: "#4e73df",
      data: [23, 21, 22, 12],
    }],
  },
```

If I manually fill labels like so it does work:

```
labels: ["val 1", "val 2"]
```

So now my question is, how do I fill the labels with values of my getData function?

Comment: Looks like you're placing an array into an array when you do:  labels: [getData()]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `labels: [getData()],` to `labels: getData(),`

This is not an array, it is an array of array

```
 labels: [getData()]
```

Comment: Aah I see, thanks for the quick and helpful respond